# Retrieve multiple rowids in SQLite insert or update, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, insert-update, rowid

I know SQLite have `last_insert_rowid()` function. I'd like to create a similar function but I want to retrieve an array of indexes, each one coming from an insert or update into my db.
To be clearer, I have a populated table like this (name is UNIQUE):

```
rowid  name   age

1     'John'  18

2     'Anne'  25

3     'Jack'  32
```

Then I have to insert or update few lines:
`('John',19), ('Michael',33), ('Jenny',12)`

Result will be:

```
rowid  name     age

1     'John'    19

2     'Anne'    25

3     'Jack'    32

4     'Michael' 33

5     'Jenny'   12
```

And rowids inserted/updated are: 1,4,5

How may I retrieve those indexes? JS answer would be nice, anyway even in other languages I suppose I should understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using two triggers. The logical flow is:

1. Create a temp table, temp_table, clone of the main table;
2. Create an insert trigger, tr_insert. This trigger verify the insertion in the main table and copy the new row also in temp_table;
3. Create an update trigger, tr_update, that acts similarly to the one in point 2, but for updates;
4. After all insertions / updates, call a function that analyze temp_table in which are rows inserted / updated.
5. Remember to call delete from temp_table after its use